# How to fix an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'm currently testing some coding for a website I'm hoping to publish in the future which will generate a line of random text when you press a button. I've followed some instructions online on how to write the code however upon testing the button no information is coming through and on opening the javascript file I receive the message:

```
Script:xxxxx
Line: 4
Char: 1
Error: Expected ']'
Code: 800A03EF
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error
```

Here is the relevant javascript:

```
var Message = [
'message 1'
'message 2'
'message 3'
'message 4'
'message 5'
'message 6'
'message 7'
'message 8'
]
```

```
function MessageDisplay() {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Message.length));
    document.getElementById('MessageDisplay').innerHTML = Message[randNum];
}
```

What I'm hoping to see when a button is clicked on the page, is a message saying something like "Message 3".  However, at the moment I'm getting nothing

Comment: Seperate array elements with comma

Comment: there you go https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Good time to learn how to use browser developer tools (F12). The syntax error displayed in the console is a big clue. Always start there and also note any errors thrown when asking questions here. Most error messages can also be searched directly in google to help give you guidance. Learning basic debugging is as important as learning to write the code itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being spiderman was hard? Jk, welcome to Stackoverflow ^^

You need to declare the array like this:

```js
var Message = [
    'message 1',
    'message 2',
    'message 3',
    'message 4',
    'message 5',
    'message 6',
    'message 7',
    'message 8'
]
```

Some commas were missing.